# How can I create multiple turtles all in different positions?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to build a crossy road sort of game through the use of the turtle package but I'm stuck on how I can create multiple different turtles (cars) that will go across my screen all at different y values.
This is literally all I have so far:

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random
from random import randint

COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
MOVE_INCREMENT = 10


class CarManager(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.color(random.choice(COLORS))
        self.setheading(180)

    def moveCars(self):
        self.fd(MOVE_INCREMENT)
```

Any ideas on how to get this result?

**I'm expecting to have many different turtle objects that can all cross the screen separately (at differemt speeds) and will all have separate y values.**

Comment: Guess you will need an object, say Game that contains a collection of Turtles. Not sure if CarManager is supposed to do that, but then I dont understand why it inherits from Turtle

Comment: Apologies you are completely right not sure why I did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as I originally intended

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
MOVE_INCREMENT = 10


class CarManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.all_cars = []

    def create_car(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1,6)
        if random_chance == 1:
            new_car = Turtle("square")
            new_car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
            new_car.penup()
            new_car.color(random.choice(COLORS))
            random_y = random.randint(-260, 260)
            new_car.goto(300, random_y)
            self.all_cars.append(new_car)

    def move_cars(self):
        for car in self.all_cars:
            car.bk(STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE)
```

Hope this can be of use to someone at some point!

**Just for reference the "random_chance" was used as a time delay only ruins the functionality of the game whereas this only reduces the number of cars.**

***Please look at [turtle graphics page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) for further information about the use of the turtle module.***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple Turtles you can simply create multiple Turtle instances:

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle1 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle2 = turtle.Turtle()

# Move turtle1
turtle1.forward(100)
# Move turtle2 somewhere else
turtle2.left(90)
turtle2.forward(100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am looking for 40+ turtles so wouldn't work the way I am intending. (It would work just unnecessary work)

Comment: you could use a list of turtles:
`turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for i in range(50)]`